# How can I force gem executables to be in placed `$HOME/.local/bin`

Tags: rubygems

I keep my user specific commands in `$HOME/.local/bin`. `pip` also installs scripts to this path.

How can force `gem install jekyll` to install jekyll executable in `$HOME/local/bin`? Currently it is installing to `$HOME/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin` which is bit annoying because with different version of ruby, this value will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, turns out to be simple. One can pass `-n $HOME/.local/bin` to `gem install`. `gem --help` has proper documentation.

```sh
$ gem install jekyll -n $HOME/.local/bin
```